# How to send a simple ping test to Flickr with Flickrj api

Tags: java, api, types, type-mismatch, flickrj

I am trying to send a single ping test to Flickr using flickrj. I am following step by step the tutorial here

https://github.com/callmeal/Flickr4Java

imported all the maven dependencies and everything and ended up with the following code:

```
import java.util.Collections;

import com.flickr4java.flickr.Flickr;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.REST;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.collections.Collection;

import com.flickr4java.flickr.test.TestInterface;

public class hello {
    public static void main(String args[]){


    String apiKey = "3f7046fe0897516df587cc3e6226f878";
    String sharedSecret = "9d0ceef5f2f3040f";
    Flickr f = new Flickr(apiKey, sharedSecret, new REST());
    TestInterface testInterface = f.getTestInterface();
    Collection results = testInterface.echo(Collections.EMPTY_MAP);

    }
}
```

I get the following error though:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collection<Element> to Collection

    at hello.main(hello.java:18)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try Collection<Element> results = testInterface.echo(Collections.EMPTY_MAP);?

Comment: @ZaidMalhis yes i forgot to mention that I had tried that and i got the following: The type Collection is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Element>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a conflict in imports, you are using com.flickr4java.flickr.collections.Collection while you most probably - as the [echo](https://github.com/callmeal/Flickr4Java/blob/58360274ff5c8efee899a59a64c3f73ac6ece6b1/Flickr4Java/src/main/java/com/flickr4java/flickr/test/TestInterface.java) method return type states - want to use java.util.Collection Class.
replace the line with:

```
java.util.Collection<Element> results = testInterface.echo(Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
```

Your Code:

```
import java.util.Collections;

import com.flickr4java.flickr.Flickr;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.REST;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.collections.Collection;

import com.flickr4java.flickr.test.TestInterface;

public class hello {
    public static void main(String args[]){


    String apiKey = "3f7046fe0897516df587cc3e6226f878";
    String sharedSecret = "9d0ceef5f2f3040f";
    Flickr f = new Flickr(apiKey, sharedSecret, new REST());
    TestInterface testInterface = f.getTestInterface();
    java.util.Collection<Element> results = testInterface.echo(Collections.EMPTY_MAP);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation [here](https://github.com/callmeal/Flickr4Java/blob/master/Flickr4Java/src/main/java/com/flickr4java/flickr/test/TestInterface.java), you would need a cast to

```
Collection<Element> results = testInterface.echo(Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
```

The signature is..

```
public Collection<Element> echo(Map<String, String> params) throws  FlickrException {
....
    return response.getPayloadCollection();
}
```

Comment: I have tried casting <Element> but then I get the following error:
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The type Collection is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with       arguments <Element>

 at hello.main(hello.java:18)
I also tried copy pasting the documentation code itself you gave and i get the same error even with that.

Comment: Some answers [here](http://solvedstack.com/questions/the-type-collection-is-not-generic-it-cannot-be-parameterized-with-arguments-extends-e) for that... you might also want to try what Zaid suggested below